# what does {{template "name" pipeline}} mean

Tags: go, go-templates

In https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions, it has the following explanation

> {{template "name" pipeline}}  The template with the specified name is
>   executed with **dot** set to the value of the pipeline.

what does it mean? what's dot for?

For example, I see the following template code -

```
{{ define "header" }}
{{ template "top" . }}
{{ template "needs" }}

...

{{ end }}
```

What is the '.' for following the "top" in the code above?

Comment: Check this just below what you linked: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value '.' is the current value or cursor as explained in the [third paragraph in the documentation](https://godoc.org/text/template):

> Annotations in the template refer to elements of the data structure (typically a field of a struct or a key in a map) to control execution and derive values to be displayed. Execution of the template walks the structure and sets the cursor, represented by a period '.' and called "dot", to the value at the current location in the structure as execution proceeds.

The command `{{ template "top" . }}` executes the template "top" with dot as the argument.  Inside "top", dot is set to the argument.